# C#: How can I rewrite my code for managing Game Data Serialization using an Array instead of a List in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to coding and I am currently working on creating scripts to serialize data to a hard drive. I have managed to get it working with a list with the type "Game". The Game class holds data that can be serialized. I have been trying to write this code to work with an array instead that has a size of 3. Unfortunately, I have been having trouble when I run my program and try to use my GUI. I just need a push in the right direction for how to approach rewriting my code. I know to start with:

```
public static Game[] savedGames = new Game[3];
```

But how do I get my definitions to work with using an array instead of a list.

```
//<SaveLoad.cs>

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System;

public static class SaveLoad {
    // Note: [ 07 / 20 / 2018]
    // 1. Make  an array of game saves index of 3. (To replace list) 
    // 2. Create definition for overwritesave()??
    // 3. Rewrite definitions Save/Load/Delete to work with an array
    // 4. Start working on custom GUI

public static List<Game> savedGames = new List<Game>(3);

public static void Save()
{
    savedGames.Add(Game.current);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + 
    "/savedGames.gd");
    Debug.Log("The file is saved at " + Application.persistentDataPath);
    bf.Serialize(file, savedGames);
    file.Close();
}

public static void Load()
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + 
        "/savedGames.gd", FileMode.Open);
        Debug.Log("The File is loaded from " + 
        Application.persistentDataPath);
        savedGames = (List<Game>)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }
}

public static void DeleteSave(int index) {

    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.gd"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + 
        "/savedGames.gd", FileMode.Open);
        savedGames = (List<Game>)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }

    savedGames.RemoveAt(index); 
    // Removes element in List from the passed Index

    BinaryFormatter bf2 = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file2 = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + 
    "/savedGames.gd"); //you can call it anything you want
    Debug.Log("Save file has been Updated at " + 
    Application.persistentDataPath);
    bf2.Serialize(file2, savedGames); // Saves Changes to Data
    file2.Close();
    }
 }
```

This is my script for the GUI. I currently have it working for a list but I am having trouble using it with an array as well. I need help finding a way to pass an index value from the menu to modify an array.

```
//<MainMenu.cs>

 using UnityEngine;
 using System;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {

 int index = 0;

 public enum Menu {
    MainMenu,
    NewGame,
    Continue,
    delete,
    caution
}

 public Menu currentMenu;

     void OnGUI () {

         GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width, Screen.height));
         GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
         GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
         GUILayout.BeginVertical();
         GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

        if(currentMenu == Menu.MainMenu) {

            GUILayout.Box("THE EIGHT");
            GUILayout.Space(10);

        if(GUILayout.Button("New Game")) {
            Game.current = new Game();
            currentMenu = Menu.NewGame;
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("Continue")) {
            SaveLoad.Load();
            currentMenu = Menu.Continue;
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("Delete Save")) {
            SaveLoad.Load();
            currentMenu = Menu.delete;
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("Quit")) {
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }

    else if (currentMenu == Menu.NewGame) {

        GUILayout.Box("Name Your Characters");
        GUILayout.Space(10);

        GUILayout.Label("Some Strange Boy");
        Game.current.Nestor.name = 
        GUILayout.TextField(Game.current.Nestor.name, 20);
        GUILayout.Label("Some Strange Girl");
        Game.current.SomeGirl.name = 
        GUILayout.TextField(Game.current.SomeGirl.name, 20);
        GUILayout.Label("Some Strange Friend");
        Game.current.SomeBro.name = 
        GUILayout.TextField(Game.current.SomeBro.name, 20);

        if(GUILayout.Button("Save")) {
            //Save the current Game as a new saved Game
            SaveLoad.Save();
            //Move on to game...
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if(GUILayout.Button("Cancel")) {
            currentMenu = Menu.MainMenu;
        }

    }

    else if (currentMenu == Menu.Continue) {

        GUILayout.Box("Select Save");
        GUILayout.Space(10);

        foreach(Game g in SaveLoad.savedGames) {
            if(GUILayout.Button(g.Nestor.name + " - " + g.SomeGirl.name + " - " + g.SomeBro.name)) {
                Game.current = g;
                //Move on to game...
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            }

        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if(GUILayout.Button("Cancel")) {
            currentMenu = Menu.MainMenu;
        }

    }

    else if (currentMenu == Menu.delete)
    {

        GUILayout.Box("Select Save to Delete");
        GUILayout.Space(10);

        foreach (Game g in SaveLoad.savedGames)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button(g.Nestor.name + " - " + g.SomeGirl.name + " 
            - " + g.SomeBro.name))
            {
                index = SaveLoad.savedGames.IndexOf(g);
                Debug.Log(index);
                currentMenu = Menu.caution;
            }

        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Cancel"))
        {
            currentMenu = Menu.MainMenu;
        }

    }
else if(currentMenu == Menu.caution) {

        GUILayout.Box("Are you sure?");
        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Yes")) {
            Debug.Log(index);
            SaveLoad.DeleteSave(index);
            currentMenu = Menu.MainMenu;
        }

           GUILayout.Space(10);
            if (GUILayout.Button("No")) {
                currentMenu = Menu.delete;
            }

        }

        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        GUILayout.EndArea();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much only need to replace your cast of a `List<Game>` to a `Game[]`.
Here's some (error unhandled) sample code infrastructure to get you started. As a hint, wrapping your file/serialization code in [`try`, `catch`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/exception) with [`IOException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SerializationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) should take care of the brunt of normal user case scenarios. It may be worth trying to mess with your `.bin` files just to see what happens and test various corner case functionality of your code.

```
void Awake() {
    //this is an object initializer, pass your Game[] in place of this
    Save(new[] {
        new Game { propertyStub = 0 },
        new Game { propertyStub = 1 },
        new Game { propertyStub = 2 }
    });

    var gA = Load();
    if(gA == null || gA.Length > 3) throw new SerializationException("Serialize error");

    foreach (var g in gA) Debug.Log(g);
}

public static void Save(Game[] gA) {
    using (var f = File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\sample.bin")) new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(f, gA);
}

public static Game[] Load() {
    using (var f = File.Open(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\sample.bin", FileMode.Open)) return (new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(f)) as Game[];
}

//Stub class used for testing purposes
[Serializable]
class Game {
    public int propertyStub { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return "propertyStub value: " + propertyStub;
    }
}
```

In addition, it's worth mentioning that the [.net Binary serializer is pretty slow in comparison to other common serialization methods](https://maxondev.com/serialization-performance-comparison-c-net-formats-frameworks-xmldatacontractserializer-xmlserializer-binaryformatter-json-newtonsoft-servicestack-text/) in general usage cases, so I advise against using it in your final builds. Other well-known serialization methods like [XML](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm) and [JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) generate very human readable output, and works well when you don't care about final file size, or serialization speed. If you really want speed and size, the [Google Protocol Buffers (Protobuf)](https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-net/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki) are a good starting point.

All of the links I've given you contain boiler-plate copy and paste code, although they all end up serializing dynamic array lists. As I said above, simply changing the explicit casts to arrays should not cause you any headache.

Comment: Very informative! Thank you so much. You gave me more than what I asked for. Well done. :)

Comment: If I have answered all your questions, it is customary to mark the answer as accepted so that focus can be given to other questions on this site ;) .